# Multiple page app - react native with native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

My first attempt of a any kind of app using react native. I am using native base for the components / styling. I have managed to get a very basic page but I am trying to work out how I go from this to a page which moves to different pages when clicked from say the footer.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navigator, Container, Content, Header, Title, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Footer, FooterTab } from 'native-base';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwesomeNativeBase extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Header>          
              <Body>
                  <Title>Kays Hairdressing</Title>
              </Body>
          </Header>
          <Content>
            <Grid>
                <Col style={{ backgroundColor: '#635DB7', height: 550 }}></Col>
                <Col style={{ backgroundColor: '#00CE9F', height: 550  }}></Col>
            </Grid>
          </Content>
          <Footer>
            <FooterTab>
                <Button>
                    <Text>Bookings</Text>
                    <Icon name="ios-book-outline" />
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Text>Blockout</Text>
                    <Icon name="ios-calendar-outline" />
                </Button>
            </FooterTab>
          </Footer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeNativeBase', () => AwesomeNativeBase);
```

I have worked out I need to use the 'navigator' option but I haven't been able to get it working as I am not sure how classes work in this setup.

Comment: I recommend you to read the code of [native-starter-kit](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit) also by native-base team. In that project there are several page transitions you can study from.

Answer (score 2):

Use a navigation library such as [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) or [React native navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

React Navigation is a JavaScript based option whereas React native navigation is a more native implementation

Give them a try

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Tabs component for screen navigation (use tabBarPosition to define the tab placing), see the [docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/COMPONENTS.html#Tabs_Default)

I don't know why FooterTab still not support screen navigation.

Comment: Pejorative. Tabs are just one navigation method. And as you point out, FooterTab is not longer even supported. For tabs, there is react-native-tab-view, but again, an overly specific answer to this general question.